# Extract called method information using roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I need to get information about a method call into a DLL using Roslyn. For example, I have the following method where dllObject is part of a DLL file.

```
 public void MyMethod()
 {
     dllObject.GetMethod();
 }
```

Is it possible to extract the method information for GetMethod such as it´s name, class name and assembly name.

Comment: Shouldn't the title be "extract called method" instead of "extract calling method"?

Comment: yes, you are right it´s updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to first search your syntax tree for an `InvocationExpressionSyntax` and then use the `SemanticModel` to retrieve the full symbol for it which should contain information about its full name (`.ToString()`), class (`.ContainingType`) and assembly (`.ContainingAssembly`).

The following example is self contained so it doesn't use an external DLL but the same approach should work for external types.

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
    public class MyClass {
            int Method1() { return 0; }
            void Method2()
            {
                int x = Method1();
            }
        }
    }");

var Mscorlib = PortableExecutableReference.CreateFromAssembly(typeof(object).Assembly);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation",
    syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { Mscorlib });
var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

//Looking at the first invocation
var invocationSyntax = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().First();
var invokedSymbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(invocationSyntax).Symbol; //Same as MyClass.Method1

//Get name
var name = invokedSymbol.ToString();
//Get class
var parentClass = invokedSymbol.ContainingType;
//Get assembly 
var assembly = invokedSymbol.ContainingAssembly;
```

I wrote a short blog post about the [`Semantic Model`](https://joshvarty.com/2014/10/30/learn-roslyn-now-part-7-introducing-the-semantic-model/) a few years ago that you might find helpful.